# Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: POST '/signup/'> error on Signup page

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a user account and all is well when I use the signup view and form to sign up on the signup HTML page below is some info but I get this error

> NoReverseMatch at /signup/ Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a
>   valid view function or pattern name. Request Method:  POST Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/ Django Version:   2.1.7 Exception
>   Type: NoReverseMatch Exception Value:  Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a
>   valid view function or pattern name. Exception
>   Location: C:\WINDOWS\system32\dev\pastebinclonedirectory\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py
>   in _reverse_with_prefix, line 622 Python
>   Executable:   C:\WINDOWS\system32\dev\pastebinclonedirectory\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version:   3.6.8 Python Path:
>   ['C:\WINDOWS\system32\dev\pastebinclonedirectory\pastebin', 
>   'C:\WINDOWS\system32\dev\pastebinclonedirectory\Scripts\python36.zip',
>   'C:\WINDOWS\system32\dev\pastebinclonedirectory\DLLs', 
>   'C:\WINDOWS\system32\dev\pastebinclonedirectory\lib', 
>   'C:\WINDOWS\system32\dev\pastebinclonedirectory\Scripts', 
>   'c:\users\aadeo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib', 
>   'c:\users\aadeo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs', 
>   'C:\WINDOWS\system32\dev\pastebinclonedirectory', 
>   'C:\WINDOWS\system32\dev\pastebinclonedirectory\lib\site-packages']
>   Server time:  Wed, 13 Mar 2019 06:46:57 +0000

**view.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(request,'app/index.html')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'app/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Userpostform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','content','private',)




class Visitorpostform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','content')
```

**urls.py** in the apps folder

```
path('',views.home,name='home'),
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'),name='login'),
path('signup/',views.signup,name='signup'),
path('accounts/profile/',views.profile,name='profile'),
path('logout',views.logout_view,name='logout'),
path('userpostnew', views.userpostnew, name='userpostnew'),
path('visitorpostnew', views.visitorpostnew, name='visitorpostnew'),
```

Comment: Can you show your template?

Answer (score 2):

you cant add html to redirect like that,

either use `render` like this

```
return render(request,'app/index.html')
```

or

```
return redirect('profile') #use name of a view declared in url to redirect to that specific page
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `request` argument inside the `redirect` function.

   The redirect function is defined as: `redirect(to, *args, permanent=False, **kwargs):`

   It has no `request` parameter.
2. Use the **name** or **route** of the path instead of the template name.

   In your case: `'home'` or `'/'` instead of `'app/index.html'`

```py
def signup(request): 
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
       ...
       return redirect('home')
       # or return redirect ('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add `reverse()` in `redirect`

use it like this

```
from django.urls import reverse
    def signup(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            form = UserRegisterForm()
        return render(request, 'app/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirect url path, must be defined in url.py file.

you can write the redirect like below

```
return redirect('/index/')
```

and the url.py
must write below

```
path('index', views.index, name = 'index')
```

and the views.py must define the index function, like below.

```
def index(request):
return render(request, 'apps/index.html')
```